# UK Employment Law Regarding errors in employment process and contract

Tags: contract-law, united-kingdom, employment, salary

So I applied for a job that was ranged from mid level/senior with me applying for the senior position with the appropriate salary.

I got through all stages of interview and was hired, but when I got my contract the title was not a senior even though I got the desired high salary.

Recently the company advertised a role for senior and the salary starting range was less than what I'm currently getting as a mid level.

I realised that everyone in this company is not ridiculously well paid, and that there's likely been some mix up and I really don't know if I should say anything or not.

Three things may have occurred,

1. I was interviewed as a mid level and hired as a mid level by the hiring manager who was not aware that my asking salary was so high and the error is in my salary.
2. I was actually hired as a senior and I'm being paid as one but there's an error in my job title instead and now I've been here for 8 months, and they literally just hired another Senior since they were still lacking.
3. For some reason I performed so well at the interview they really wanted me so badly they are willing to pay me a senior salary to perform a mid level role.

What are the implications of this, have they broken any laws or have I?

What should I do? Should I do anything at all?

Is this running foul of fair payment laws since I am being paid so much more than my peers?

Comment: 1. Your phrasing risks your question being closed on the grounds that it seems to be asking for advice about specific, real circumstances. 2. In the UK it's legal to pay a 'junior' more than a 'senior'. 3. In terms of your title and salary, surely they are what you and your employer agreed between you? In which case, what is the mistake? 4. In terms of the advert, presumably your employer believes that the advertised salary is adequate to attract candidates for the role. 5. For peace of mind, perhaps call ACAS on 0300 123 1100. I think ACAS will say you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

There are no “fair payment laws”, except for some limited exceptions that probably don’t apply here (presuming that no one is being paid less than the minimum wage, and you’re not being paid more than someone with equivalent qualifications, experience and responsibility who is of a different gender, race, religion or other protected characteristic). Companies can pay whatever they want as long as they pay at least the minimum wage and they’re not giving unfair treatment to people with a protected characteristic under discrimination laws.